# Which of Arrow's four desirable properties' is violated in this scenario?

Tags: social-choice

So the scenario is as follows: there are 3 agents and 4 alternatives, $a,b,c,$ and $d$. Society's ranking of the 4 alternatives is such that

> the highest-ranked alternative is agent 1's highest-ranked
>   alternative,
>
> The alternative that agent 2 ranks highest among the three remaining alternatives is ranked second highest by society
>
> The alternative that agent 3 ranks highest among the two remaining alternatives is ranked third highest by society.
>
> Society ranks the 4th alternative lowest.

So my interpretation of the ranking would look something like this:

[image]

Which of Arrow's four desirable properties is violated?

I'm guessing that the "Unanimity" preference would be violated, because agent 2 prefers $b$ over $c$, but this is not reflected in society's ranking?

The four desired properties I am referring to are:

1/ Complete and transitive preferences

2/ Respect unanimity

3/ Non-dictatorial outcomes

4/ Independence of irrelevant alternatives

Comment: What happens if they all rank $a$ highest?

Comment: Can you specify *which four* properties you're considering?

Comment: @HerrK. I've now added these four properties to my question

Comment: @denesp according to the setup, only agent 1 ranks $a$ highest; other agents highest rankings are as shown in the table. No additional information was said about agents 1,2, and 3's rankings for their 2nd to 4th preferences.

Comment: @denesp I've also updated the scenario so that the ranking procedure is a little clearer.

Comment: I think this kind of answers your question. These properties have to hold over universal domain.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what unanimity means here. If *all* voters prefer alternative $x$ to $y$, so must the social ranking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that an alternative being highest-ranked by an agent involves comparisons with all other alternatives, which raises doubts that your method satisfies *independence of irrelevant alternatives*. Indeed, it does not.  Independence off irrelevant alternatives is actually the only property that is violated.

Here are two profiles, only the preferences of the first two agents matter in them, so I will not specify the preferences of the other agents. I only assume the other agents preferences are the same in both profiles.

Agent 1, Profile $1$: $a\succ b\succ c\succ d$

Agent 2, Profile $1$: $b\succ a\succ c\succ d$

In Profile 1, the social ranking of $a$ and $b$ is $a\succ b$.

Agent 1, Profile $2$: $c\succ a\succ b\succ d$

Agent 2, Profile $2$: $b\succ a\succ c\succ d$

In Profile 2, the social ranking of $a$ and $b$ is $b\succ a$.

Since the relative ranking of $a$ and $b$ is the same in both profiles, independence of irrelevant alternatives is violated.

Comment: Is there a typo in your Agent 1, Profile 2? Why are there 5 rankings, with $a$ appearing twice?

Comment: @user98937 You are right; I corrected the typo.